# How to get capacity of NSMutableArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have following code:

```
[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:slidingValue]
```

However, if I try to get the size of it by using `count` directly after above initialisation, it will return 0. There is no adding object into it yet though.

Am I able to get the capacity of it?

Comment: `NSMutableArray` does not have an initial fixed size. It grows as you add elements. The `capacity` in `initWithCapacity:` is just a hint for performance purposes, I think. See the docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/initWithCapacity:

Comment: Hmm...Im wondering why you need the capacity of a NSMutaleArray? It look like a XY problem.

Comment: When you have slidingValue which you have set as capacity then why you need the same from array ? you can use slidingValue this one which you have already assigned to array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You don't need the capacity.** It's an optimization, and depending on how large a capacity you specify and what internal algorithm `NSArray` chooses, might actually be ignored. Just add the objects when you get them, using -`addObject:` or -`insertObject:`. Different from a `CFArray`, the capacity of an `NSArray` isn't a hard limit. It's just a suggestion.

If you get your objects in a random order (but with an index number), you could create an array and fill it with `[NSNull null]` objects using -`addObject:`, then replace the `NSNull` with the actual object as you get it. But the latter is rarely needed.

**Note:**

The -`initWithCapacity:` method creates an empty array with a hint of how large the array can reach before a memory reallocation. The count increases when you actually `-addObject`: to the array.